# Need help converting Jquery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As said, I have no idea how to do JQuery, Would this be possible?

Jquery:

```
<script>

$('#player').on('timeupdate', function() {
    $('#seekbar').attr("value", this.currentTime / this.duration);
});?

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    document.getElementById('seekbar').value = this.currentTime / this.duration;
}, false);
```